# WUBI boot error

Tags: boot, ubuntu-netbook, wubi, windows-xp, flicker

I installed wubi netbook edition a week back from win xp service pack 2

When I boot into Ubuntu the screen flickers and it reboots.

Now I don't have Windows anymore on my notebook asus L3800.

It just shows:

- Ubuntu generic
- Ubuntu recovery
- Ubuntu netbook

Now which one should I go in to reboot?

I don't want to access Windows anymore in the future.

I don't have any cd to reinstall it as i am comfortable with Ubuntu.

I get 2 boo chain loader:

- with generic, I get a quiet silence in insmod
- with netbook, I get  instrid

Comment: This question appears to be abandonded, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that.

Answer (score 0):

You have to install the full Ubuntu version to work without Windows.

1. Burn the Ubuntu iso on a USB stick or on a CD/DVD.
2. Insert the USB/CD/DVD.
3. Boot from it
4. Install Ubuntu. Create partitions or remove everything on your computer and install it.
5. Now it should work.

WUBI is not a full version of Ubuntu, it's a test version.

I hope this helped you,

Daniel

Comment: please tell me step by step i have nil in dos and beginner in ubuntu

Comment: @Faiza As I said, burn a CD on another computer. http://www.ubuntu.com/netbook/get-ubuntu/download